# Toggle text of a button when clicked

Tags: javascript, html

I have been trying to change the text of a button when it gets clicked.

this is the button

```
 <button id="1" onclick="showhide(); toggle();" > Open </button>
```

this is the js

```
function toggle(button)
  {
    if(document.getElementById("1").value=="Open"){
     document.getElementById("1").value="Close";}

    else if(document.getElementById("1").value=="Close"){
     document.getElementById("1").value="Open";}
```

It never changes from "Open" however. Thanks for any help

Comment: where is your showhide func?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this function, but you can directly call the `toggle` function directly from the button.

```
<button id="button_1" onclick="toggle()">Open</button>
```

```js
function showhide() {
  // Extra code here...
  toggle();
}

function toggle() {
  var button = document.getElementById('button_1');
  
  if (button.innerHTML == "Open") {
    button.innerHTML = "Close";
  } else {
    button.innerHTML = "Open";
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="button_1" onclick="showhide()">Open</button>
```

Comment: works perfectly, thank you so much. I should have put more detail in my question however, my Button was supposed to be ````<button id="1" onclick="showhide(); toggle();" > Open </button>````

Answer (score 2):

the name of the function on the definition is toggle and in the call is showhide

try this

```
<body>
   <button id="1" onclick="showhide()"> Open </button>

   <script>
       function showhide() {

           console.log('clicked', document.getElementById("1").innerText);

           if (document.getElementById("1").innerText == "Open") {
               document.getElementById("1").innerText = "Close";
           }

           else if (document.getElementById("1").innerText == "Close") {
               document.getElementById("1").innerText = "Open";
           }
       }
   </script>
</body>
```